# Fork() and && shorticircuiting in C

Tags: c, fork

I understand fork, need help understanding why

```
if(fork() && !fork())
```

Does not evaluate the second fork procedure in the first child process.

Parent returns [X|x>0] ^ ![Y|y>0]
child.0 returns 0 and does not call second fork procedure
child.1 returns [X|x>0] ^ !0

Why does child.0 not call the second fork procedure?

Thanks

Comment: You've already answered your own question; because of short-circuit behaviour of `&&`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, I was thinking the same thing...

Answer (score 2):

If the left operand of `&&` evaluates to 0 (false), then the whole expression will evaluate to 0 (false) regardless of the value of the right operand, so the right operand isn't evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&&` operator and if terminates immediately once evaluation returns 0. Basically, if executes from left to right and in the case of `&&` operators termination is immediante once 0(or false) is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

the second `fork()` is not called when the first `fork()` returns 0 because the boolean expression `(0 && fork())` will always be 0, no matter what `fork()` returns. Therefore, to improve performance the second `fork()` is short-circuited and not executed.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value of fork() is not what the child returns as you seem to think, when you say that child returns something. To check that you must use wait().